# text_to_image - how to use (python3)

Tags: python-3.x, package

I installed [this package](https://pypi.org/project/text-to-image/) in python3. How to use it? I followed the instruction and I got this errors:

```
linux@LINUXMINT:~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/text_to_image$ python3 decode.py image.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decode.py", line 60, in <module>
    print(decode(args.image_path))
  File "decode.py", line 27, in decode
    decoded_text += chr(pixel_value)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
linux@LINUXMINT:~/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/text_to_image$ python3 decode.py -f my-text-file.txt image.png
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "decode.py", line 62, in <module>
    output_file = decode_to_file(args.image_path, args.file)
  File "decode.py", line 44, in decode_to_file
    decoded_text = decode(image_path)
  File "decode.py", line 27, in decode
    decoded_text += chr(pixel_value)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type tuple)
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is giving you error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following and it works just fine:

```
$ python3 encode.py -t "Hello World!" image.png  # encodes given text
$
$ INFO:root:Image 'image.png' has been created


$ python3 decode.py image.png  # decodes a given image
$ 
$ Hello World!
```

Make sure you use encode.py and decode.py provided with the library.